Need help implementing an explosive wave knockBack effect for enemies when opening a chest in Unity
I’m working on a chest system in my Unity game where, upon opening a chest, I want nearby enemies to be pushed outward in all directions, creating an explosive wave effect. Currently, I have a script that handles the knockback, but the enemies do not move correctly from the center of the chest outward.
Below, I'm sharing the PowerUpChest script I'm using. The KnockBackNearbyEnemies method is responsible for applying the knockback to the enemies, but the direction they are pushed is not correct. They disperse, but I want them to move from the center outward.
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this logic so that enemies move outward correctly from the center of the chest, this is the closest I got. Here’s my code:
{
    [SerializeField] private PickUpBasePermanent[] potentialPowerUps;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer theSr;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite chestOpen;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject notification;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI priceTxt;
    [SerializeField] private Transform spawnPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float scaleSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float disappearDelay = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float knockBackForce = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask enemyLayer;

    private bool canOpen;
    private bool isOpen;
    private int chestPrice;

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleChestInteraction();
        HandleChestScaling();
    }

    private void HandleChestInteraction()
    {
        if (canOpen && !isOpen && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (DropPickUpManager.instance.GetCurrentCoins() >= chestPrice)
            {
                DropPickUpManager.instance.SpendCoins(chestPrice);
                UIManager.instance.UpdateGoldUI();
                InstantiatePowerUp();
                KnockBackNearbyEnemies();
                AudioManager.instance.PlaySFX(2);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowUnablePurchaseNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleChestScaling()
    {
        if (isOpen)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localScale, Vector3.one, scaleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void ShowUnablePurchaseNotification()
    {
        notification.transform.DOShakePosition(0.5f, new Vector3(10f, 5f, 0), vibrato: 20, randomness: 90, fadeOut: true);
        AudioManager.instance.PlaySFX(53);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !isOpen)
        {
            notification.SetActive(true);
            priceTxt.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            canOpen = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !isOpen)
        {
            notification.SetActive(false);
            priceTxt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            canOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private void InstantiatePowerUp()
    {
        int powerUp = Random.Range(0, potentialPowerUps.Length);
        PickUpBasePermanent powerUpInstance = Instantiate(potentialPowerUps[powerUp], spawnPoint.position, transform.rotation);

        theSr.sprite = chestOpen;

        priceTxt.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        notification.SetActive(false);

        isOpen = true;
        canOpen = false;

        ChangeScale();
        StartCoroutine(DestroyChestAfterDelay());
    }

    private void ChangeScale()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f);
    }

    public void SetPrice(int _price)
    {
        chestPrice = _price;
        priceTxt.text = _price.ToString() + "G";
    }

    private IEnumerator DestroyChestAfterDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(disappearDelay);
        theSr.DOFade(0f, 1f).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        });
    }

    private void KnockBackNearbyEnemies()
    {
        Collider2D[] enemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, knockBackForce, enemyLayer);

        foreach (Collider2D enemy in enemies)
        {
            KnockBack knockBackComponent = enemy.GetComponent<KnockBack>();

            if (knockBackComponent != null)
            {
                Vector3 direction = (enemy.transform.position - transform.position).normalized; // Get direction from the chest
                knockBackComponent.TriggerKnockBack(direction, knockBackForce); // Apply knockback in that direction
            }
        }
    }
}```

and my knockBack script:

public class KnockBack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Action OnKnockBackStart;
    public Action OnKnockBackEnd;

    [SerializeField] private float knockBackTime = .2f;

    private Vector3 hitDirection;
    private float knockBackForce;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        OnKnockBackStart += ApplyKnockBackForce;
        OnKnockBackEnd += ResetKnockBack;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        OnKnockBackStart -= ApplyKnockBackForce;   
        OnKnockBackEnd -= ResetKnockBack;
    }
    public void TriggerKnockBack(Vector3 _hitDirection, float _knockBackForce)
    {
        hitDirection = _hitDirection;
        knockBackForce = _knockBackForce;
        OnKnockBackStart?.Invoke();
    }


    private void ApplyKnockBackForce()
    {
        ApplyForce();
        StartCoroutine(KnockBackCo());
    }

    private void ApplyForce()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (transform.position - hitDirection).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(direction * knockBackForce * rb.mass, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void ResetKnockBack()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private IEnumerator KnockBackCo()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(knockBackTime);
        OnKnockBackEnd?.Invoke();    
    }
}


Why are you doing this subtraction? Vector3 direction = (transform.position - hitDirection).normalized; — you already have a direction as input, which has already taken the enemy position into account. You don't need to account for it twice.

You’re right that the knockback direction can be calculated directly from the enemy's position and the chest's position without needing to subtract it twice. I will make those adjustments in my code to simplify the logic.
However, I'm still having trouble getting the enemies to truly disperse from the center outward like an explosive wave. If you have any additional suggestions on how to achieve this effect?

update: it worked! Now, it applies the knockback effect as intended, and everything is functioning properly. Thank you!

If you have a solution, you can always selfanswer the question and post your updated code

I'm not sure what you mean by "truly disperse" — is there some other aspect you still need help with?
